# Github markdown { symbol with red background

Tags: github, markdown, readme

Why the second symbol "{" on my repository [README.md](https://github.com/Amimaro/image-search-abstraction-layer-api/blob/master/README.md) have a red background?

The code used was

````
## Example output - latest:
```json
{ { "term": "", "when": "" } ... }
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON format is incorrect. The outer object does not have a key to label the value which is the inner object.

Github uses the red background to show that there is a problem in your syntax, which in this case is that the structure of your JSON object is invalid.

Try using something like:

````
```json
{ "key": { "term": "", "when": "" } ... }
```
````

If you were trying to represent an array of objects, use something along these lines:

````
```json
[ { "term": "", "when": "" } ... ]
```
````